# redefine static methods with ByteBuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

Can homebody help me please to give me a hint how to redefine static methods using byte-buddy 1.6.9  ?

I have tried this :

```
public class Source {
    public  static String hello(String name) {return null;}
}


public class Target {
    public static String hello(String name) {
        return "Hello" + name+ "!";
    }
}
String helloWorld = new ByteBuddy()
                .redefine(Source.class)               
                .method(named("hello"))
                .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Target.class))
                .make()
                .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
                .getLoaded()
                .newInstance()
                .hello("World");
```

I got following Exception :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot inject already loaded type: class delegation.Source

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Classes can only be loaded once by each class loader. In order to replace a method, you would need to use a Java agent to hook into the JVM's HotSwap feature.

Byte Buddy provides a class loading strategy that uses such an agent, use:

```
.load(Source.class.getClassLoader(), 
      ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
```

This does however require you to install a Java agent. On a JDK, you can do so programmatically, by `ByteBuddyAgent.install()` (included in the byte-buddy-agent artifact). On a JVM, you have to specify the agent on the command line.

Comment: Rafael,If I want to rebase the  hello() static method of the Source class in the redefined method of the Target class how can I still call the original static method of  Source class ?  Thank you so much !

Comment: Have a look at the `Advice` class where you can add code before and after the original method and also skip the method conditionally. Other than that, you can only rebase a class to retain original implementations.

Comment: Do you know about any example somewhere about how to use the Advice class ? Thanks !

Comment: Is still not clear for me how can I have access to the original static method and how to return a different value in the rebased static method. For example : public static newRebasedmethod() { originalStaticMethod(); return myNewReturnValue;} Do you have a hint for me ?  Thanks !

Comment: The supercall anotation should do that for you.

Comment: Hmm, when I add @SuperCall Callable<?> superMethod as an additional  parameter of the hello() method in the Target class, I get **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of [net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@ab47bfd] allows for delegation from public static java.lang.String delegation.Source.hello(java.lang.String)** .

Comment: Then you are not using rebase, I assume. If you want to preserve the original code AND redefine a class, you must use `Advice`.

Comment: Which chances do I have with Advice to change the return value or to conditionally call the original static method ? Is there some equivalent of the @SuperCall that can be used with Advice ? Thanks !

Comment: Its a bit more complicated. For an exit advice, you can set a return value by using `@Return` with `readOnly = false`. From the enter advice, you can choose to skip the original code by returning an appropriate value. Its all in the javadoc.

Comment: If I have different aspects to implement for different methods in a class, I suppose I need different Advice classes for every method that I want to instrument I suppose, am I right ? Because one Advice class has one enter and one exit advice...

Comment: You can aggregate adivces. Ideally, you have a single advice for each concern.